# How to extract the text value from dynamically created text input boxes via a button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with properly extracting the "values" inputted into a "text box" that was dynamically created based on desired user input. My problem right now is my "print usr" button is not calling the function to print out the values typed into the text boxes. I'm not getting any errors in the console so I am completely baffled as to why it is not working.

**I would greatly appreciate help on this matter, change the code completely or just tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it please!**

Here is a general idea of how it currently works with the GUI with my HTML and JS code:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="elemCreator.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <b>Input # of users:</b>
    <form id="usr_form" name="usr_form" method="get" action="mainmenu.html" onsubmit="elemCreator.createUserEntry(document.usr_form.usr_num.value);return false;">
        <input type="text" name="usr_num">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function elementCreator () {
    this.usrList = [];
}

var elemCreator = new elementCreator();

elementCreator.prototype.createUserEntry = function (usr_num) {
    for (i = 0; i < usr_num; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += '<b>User #' + (i + 1) + ': </b><br>';
        this.usrList[i] = document.createElement("INPUT");
        this.usrList[i].setAttribute("type","text");
        document.body.appendChild(this.usrList[i]);

        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }

    document.body.innerHTML += '<form onsubmit="elemCreator.printUsrs(usr_num); return false;">';
    document.body.innerHTML += '<input type="submit" value="Print User Names">';
    document.body.innerHTML += '</form>';
}

//Using this function below just to see whether or not the text values are being saved to the array
elementCreator.prototype.printUsrs = function (usr_num) {
    for (i = 0; i < usr_num; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + this.usrList[i].value;
    }
}
```

My current HTML GUI:

[image]

The current HTML GUI works, but the button at bottom does not.

Comment: Incrementally adding markup to the document is not a good idea, especially when you are adding closing tags in a separate operation to the related opening tag. Concatenate the markup into a single string and write it all at once, making sure it's valid markup on its own.

Comment: What is the value for *usr_num* that is passed to *printUsrs*? Seems to be undefined, so the loop doesn't loop.

Comment: @RobG gives two great hints as to why this code isn't working, but it's also probably time to learn to use jQuery or a templating tool like Handlebars (or possibly React). This kind of direct DOM manipulation is notoriously hard to get right, particularly in a cross-platform way.

Comment: Never used jQuery, will definitely look into it since I've tried too many different variations and still cannot get this to work the way I want. It's especially frustrating since it seems to be a simple task to perform and I have used the "text" extraction via "button" with <form> before, yet this time when I need to have a dynamic number of "users" it tosses it into chaos.

Comment: I disagree with smarx's comment about DOM manipulation being difficult without a library like jQuery. If jQuery was used in the same way in this case, it would have similar (possibly worse) issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example using jQuery:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html { font-family: Arial; }
        input.name { margin-bottom: 20px; }
        button { display: block; }
        h2 { margin: 0; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Input # of users:</h3>
    <form id="user-form">
        <input type="text" id="number-of-users">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        function createUserEntries(numberOfUsers) {
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
                $(document.body).append($('<h2>').text('User #' + (i + 1) + ': '));
                $(document.body).append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('name'));
            }

            var button = $('<button>').text('Print User Names').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                printUsers();
            });
            $(document.body).append(button);
        }

        function printUsers() {
            $('input.name').each(function () {
                $(document.body).append($('<p>').text($(this).val()));
            });
        }

        $(function () {
            $('#user-form').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                createUserEntries($('#number-of-users').val());
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great intro piece for me to use jQuery more often.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RobG.  I reproduced your code in jsbin to investigate and found the form element closes itself before the submit button is added. So the submit button is actually outside the form.

I fixed this by adding your form and input button on one line.

Also to keep track of the number of inputs dynamically generated I found one way of making it work. I added a classname when generating the inputs.  Then onsubmit gets all inputs with that classname and stores that in an array and prints all values to the screen.

Hope this helps and I didn't mutilate your code too much:
https://jsbin.com/loritaxoko/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML property/method is not a DOM method - people don't seem to understand this difference - innerHTML is an a DHTML property/method.

It is never completely safe to use innerHTML property to create UI elements.
UI elements are not exactly html elements, they are browser built in controls and they might just not get completely initialized if they've been made present after the page load by using plain html.

Consider using DOM methods like createElement("UI Type") and append..., instead.